# Morphism of rings and localization

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $ \varphi : A \to B $ be a morphism of rings. Why are the two following assertions equivalent:

$ 1) $ There exists a multiplicative subset $ S $ of the ring $ A $, and an ideal $ I $ of $ A $, such that the $ A $-algebra $ B $ is identified to $ S^{-1} A / IS^{-1}A $.

$ 2) $ $ \forall b \in B $ : $ b = \dfrac{ \varphi (a)}{\varphi (s)} $ such that $ a,s \in A $ and $ \varphi ( s ) \in B^{ \times } $.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What do the elements of $S^{-1}A/IS^{-1}A$ actually look like, and what does (2) say about what the elements of $B$ look like?

Comment: $ u \in S^{-1} A / IS^{-1} A $ if and only if : $ u = \dfrac{a}{s} + IS^{-1} A $ with $ a \in A $ and $ s \in S $. no ?

Comment: And that is essentially what (2) is saying the elements of $B$ look like.

Comment: I don't understand why. Thanks in advance, for help.  :-((

Answer (score 3):

(1) => (2) is clear (if not, recall the definitions of localizations and quotients).

Now assume that (2) holds. Let $S = \{a \in A : \phi(a) \in B^\times\}$ and $I = \ker(\phi)$. The universal property of localizations gives us a morphism of $A$-algebras $S^{-1} A \to B$. It vanishes on the image of  $I$. Then, the universal property of quotients gives us a morphism of $A$-algebras $S^{-1} A / I S^{-1} A \to B$. By assumotion (2) it is surjective. Now let us consider an element in the kernel. It is the residue class of a fraction $\dfrac{a}{s}$ (with $s \in S$) such that $\dfrac{\phi(a)}{\phi(s)}=0$ in $B$. If we multiply with $\phi(s) \in B^\times$, we get $\phi(a)=0$, i.e. $a \in I$. But then $\dfrac{a}{s} \in I S^{-1} A$, i.e. its residue class vanishes. $\square$

*Addendum.* If $\phi : A \to B$ is a homomorphism of rings, we can consider the smallest subring $B'$ of $B$ which contains the images of $\phi$ and the inverses of the invertible images of $\phi$. Hence, $A \to B$ factors as $A \to B' \to B$, where $B' \to B$ is an inclusion and $A \to B'$ is a composition of a localization and a regular quotient. Furthermore, $B' \to B$ has the property that $B'^\times = B' \cap B^\times$. Actually $B'$ is the smallest $A$-subalgebra of $B$ with this property.